# Assembly win64 api stack reserve size extra 8-byte why

Tags: assembly, x86-64, win64

i have a problem with stack reserve size for win64 api use ....

i know that i have to reserve stack for win64 api functions and the size of reserve Must be (8 * Count of Parameters) + 8

for example, for

```
BOOL WriteFile(
  HANDLE       hFile,
  LPCVOID      lpBuffer,
  DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

function, there are 5 parameters so it's (8 * 5 = 40) and also + 8 = 48 but in GCC, i compiled a file (win64) and i saw it's reserved 56 byte instead of 48 byte !

an other example,

```
HANDLE CreateFileA(
  LPCSTR                lpFileName,
  DWORD                 dwDesiredAccess,
  DWORD                 dwShareMode,
  LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
  DWORD                 dwCreationDisposition,
  DWORD                 dwFlagsAndAttributes,
  HANDLE                hTemplateFile
);
```

which has 7 parameters so (7 * 8 = 56 + 8 = 64) but it GCC reserves 72-BYTE ... what is this extra 8-BYTE ?

Also i have an other question about this ... why some other functions that have less than 4 parameters, GCC never reserves stack for them ?

Comment: presumably to maintain 16-byte stack alignment before a `call`.

Comment: still it's not understandable .... for example, for the first function, i said it Must be (48-BYTE) but GCC sets (56-BYTE) ... 48 byte is ok for 16-bit alignment ! why GCC adds another 8-BYTE to it ? !